# Consulta sobre algunos parrafos de html

Tags: html, css

buenas noches tengo el siguiente codigo

```html
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-size: 11.0pt; font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif;">Los elementos que aqu&iacute; se entregan son y ser&aacute;n de la empresa en todo momento, en caso de terminaci&oacute;n del contrato de trabajo o la entrega de un nuevo equipo, usted se compromete a hacer devoluci&oacute;n del equipo.</span></strong></p>
```

pero no quiero que quede asi quiero que quede asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me queda asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tiene que encajar asi[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es lo que estás buscando.

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <p style="text-align: left;">
    <strong>
    <span style="font-size: 11.0pt; font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif;">
        Los elementos que aqu&iacute; se entregan son y ser&aacute;n de la empresa en todo momento, en caso de terminaci&oacute;n del contrato de trabajo o la entrega de un nuevo equipo, usted se compromete a hacer devoluci&oacute;n del equipo.
    </span>
    </strong>
    </p>

<p style="text-align: left;">
    <strong>
    <span style="font-size: 11.0pt; font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif;">
        Los elementos que aqu&iacute; se entregan son y ser&aacute;n de la empresa en todo momento, en caso de terminaci&oacute;n del contrato de trabajo o la entrega de un nuevo equipo, usted se compromete a hacer devoluci&oacute;n del equipo.
    </span>
    </strong>
    </p>

<p style="text-align: left;">
    <strong>
    <span style="font-size: 11.0pt; font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif;">
        Los elementos que aqu&iacute; se entregan son y ser&aacute;n de la empresa en todo momento, en caso de terminaci&oacute;n del contrato de trabajo o la entrega de un nuevo equipo, usted se compromete a hacer devoluci&oacute;n del equipo.
    </span>
    </strong>
    </p>

<p style="text-align: left;">
    <strong>
    <span style="font-size: 11.0pt; font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif;">
        Los elementos que aqu&iacute; se entregan son y ser&aacute;n de la empresa en todo momento, en caso de terminaci&oacute;n del contrato de trabajo o la entrega de un nuevo equipo, usted se compromete a hacer devoluci&oacute;n del equipo.
    </span>
    </strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

[image: 11]

[image: 22]

Comment: si pa gracias esta  cooooorrecto ejejej

Answer (score 0):

No se si te he entendido bien pero quieres justificar el texto no ?

```
text-aling: justify;
```

Tambien debes meterlo dentro de un div y centrar dicho div.

```html
 <html>
  <body>
   <div id="contenedor" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 500px; border:1px solid black; padding: 10px">
    <p style="text-align: justify;"><strong><span style="font-size: 11.0pt; 
    font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif;">Los elementos que aqu&iacute; se 
    entregan 
    son y ser&aacute;n de la empresa en todo momento, en caso de 
    terminaci&oacute;n del contrato de trabajo o la entrega de un nuevo 
    equipo, 
    usted se compromete a hacer devoluci&oacute;n del equipo.</span>
    </strong>
   </p>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: no no funciono sigue sacandolo igual en plan alargado por todo el ancho y quiero que solo ocupe como la primera iomagen

Comment: No puede ser en la ejecución el texto sale justificado, explica bien que es lo que quieres conseguir para que te entienda.

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta, te lo he puesto en un div, y te lo he centrado, mira a ver si es eso lo que necesitabas

Comment: quedo mas demasiado delgado

Comment: no no quiero que quede dentro de un div gracias osea con la margen

Answer (score 0):

Lo estás alineando al centro. Alinea a la izquierda.
Además, deberías de meterlo en un DIV que te limite el ancho, así que deberías de tener algo así:

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <p style="text-align: left;">
    <strong>
    <span style="font-size: 11.0pt; font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif;">
        Los elementos que aqu&iacute; se entregan son y ser&aacute;n de la empresa en todo momento, en caso de terminaci&oacute;n del contrato de trabajo o la entrega de un nuevo equipo, usted se compromete a hacer devoluci&oacute;n del equipo.
    </span>
    </strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

Prueba esto, ya verás.

[image: captura]

Comment: si pa que pena pero no me queda bien adjunto a la pregunta la imagen que digo

Comment: Con lo que te he puesto, solo tienes que ir añadiendo  nuevos p, strong y span dentro del mismo DIV y meter dentro las tablas y el texto. Cada p tiene que tener `style="text-align:left;"`  y ya está.

Comment: No si pero el resto del documento ya esta hecho solo falta la parte final pero no se porque sale asi solo tiene que salir como esta arriba pero con negrita